# Select Hex/Char conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encoding, sql-server-2012, hex

I have some data in a SQL database stored in the format below, which I would like to convert to a readable string:

```
540045005300540049004E00470031003200330034
```

I would like to run some kind of SELECT statement to return the text which should be `TESTING1234`

It appears to be in Hex format separated by 00 between each character, so if I run these statements:

```
SELECT CHAR(0x54)
SELECT CHAR(0x45)
```

This returns:

```
T
E
```

Is there any way I can convert the whole string in one statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `00` point to *2-byte-enocding* which is represented as `NVARCHAR`. Try this

```
SELECT CAST(0x540045005300540049004E00470031003200330034 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Or directly from the HEX-string as string:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),'540045005300540049004E00470031003200330034',2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

The result is *TESTING1234*

### Some more background on string encoding

SQL-Server knows exactly two types of strings:

- *1-byte-encoded* VARCHAR / CHAR
- *2-byte-encoded* nVARCHAR / nCHAR

The 1-byte string is *extended ASCII*, the related collation provides a code page to map non-plain-latin characters (it is **not** utf-8 as people sometimes tell).

The 2-byte string is UCS-2 (almost the same as utf-16).

I've corrected the word *unicode* above, as it is not correct actually.

There are many encodings SQL-Server will not be able to interpret natively.

The string above *looks* like it is good for `NVARCHAR`, but this is not guaranteed in any case.

### Some more background on binary encoding

SQL-Server knows `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` as a real BLOB-Type. In the result of a `SELECT` they are presented as HEX-string and in a script you can use a HEX-string as native input. But it is important to know, that this **HEX-string is not the actual value!**, just the human readable representation on a computer screen.

And there is a real string, which *looks* like a HEX-string (but isn't).

```
0x123 != '0x123'
```

If you have a string, which is a HEX-string, but is coming to you as "normal" string (e.g. in a text based container like a CSV file or an XML) you have to convert this.

And, not really related to this question, just to mention it: There are more string based binary representers like base64.

### Some examples

```sql
--start with a normal string 
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='This is a test to explain conversions from string to hex to binary and back';
--see the HEX string (real binary!)
SELECT CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX)) ThisIsTheHexStringOfTheString;

--I copy the binary behind the "=" _wihtout_ quotes
DECLARE @ThisIsTheBinary VARBINARY(MAX)=0x546869732069732061207465737420746F206578706C61696E20636F6E76657273696F6E732066726F6D20737472696E6720746F2068657820746F2062696E61727920616E64206261636B;
--This can be re-casted directly
SELECT CAST(@ThisIsTheBinary AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ThisIsReconvertedBinary;

--there is an undocumented function providing a HEX-string from a binary
DECLARE @aHEXstring VARCHAR(MAX)=sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX)));
--This string looks exactly the same as above, but it is a string
SELECT @aHEXstring AS ThisIsStringWhichLooksLikeHEX;

--You can use dynamic SQL
EXEC('SELECT CAST(' + @aHEXstring + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS CastedViaDynamicSQL');
--or CONVERT's abilities (read the documentation!)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@aHEXstring,1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ConvertedViaCONVERT
```

Comment: More specifically, this seems to be a `UTF-16LE` Unicode transformation. Does an `NVARCHAR` assume this encoding by default? What if you need a different ont?

Comment: So it's UCS-2 instead of Unicode. Excellent explanation by the way.